# Extract single property from Get-Counter object

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to do performance monitoring and would like to return the Percent CPU for a given process PID as a whole number.  I get the PID from the Get-Process applet (along with the username for correlation) and correlate that to the process name before getting the CPU percentage. The code up until my dilema is as follows:

```
$ProcessPID = "<PID of running instance of a program>"
$ProcessName = (Get-Process -Id $ProcessPID).Name
$CpuCores = (Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem).NumberOfLogicalProcessors
$Samples = (Get-Counter "\Process($Processname*)\% Processor Time").CounterSamples
$Samples | Select @{Expression={[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)}}
```

This works fine and returns an object like this:

**[Decimal]::Round(($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores), 2)
-------------------------------------------------**
6.98

What I need is to return just the value '6.98'.

I've tried using $Samples.CookedValue (which shows as a property when I pipe the object to the 'gm' command), converting the object to a string and using RexEx to extract the whole number (I used an online regex builder to ensure the expression was correct) but nothing has worked thus far. The entire object is always returned.  So, in a nutshell, I need to know how to extract just the value from the get-counter object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-Object` creates new objects and objects have properties and values, if you want a single value or an array of values then don't use it:

```
$Samples | ForEach-Object { [math]::Round($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores, 2) }
```

If you want to have objects but with a property name of your choice, then add the [`Name` or `Label` key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3#-property) to your [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3):

```
$Samples | Select-Object @{ Name = 'myPropertyName'; Expression = { [math]::Round($_.CookedValue / $CpuCores, 2) }}
```